# Pandas: How to add a new column of Group ID to a dataframe based on the loop of a column of index sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

| Index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | xxxxxxx | yyyy |
| 1 | xxxxxx | yyy |
| 2 | xxxxx | yy |
| 0 | xxx | y |
| 1 | xx | yyyyy |

What I want is to add a new column to represent Group ID based on the loop of column `Index`. A new Group ID is required when `Index` resets to 0.

like this:

| Index | Column1 | Column2 | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | xxxxxxx | yyyy | 1 |
| 1 | xxxxxx | yyy | 1 |
| 2 | xxxxx | yy | 1 |
| 0 | xxx | y | 2 |
| 1 | xx | yyyyy | 2 |

Please give me instructions, thanks

Comment: what is your condition to get the GroupId ?

Comment: based on the loop of Index

Comment: So sorry to make you confused. Column1 and Column2 is just for referrence and there is no meaning at all. Group ID is totally based on the loop of Index when it resets to 0. @user96564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned:

> represent Group ID **based on the loop of Index**

If you mean that a new group is formed whenever `Index` reset to `0`, you can try:

```
df['Group ID'] = df['Index'].eq(0).cumsum()
```

Or, if you mean a new group is formed whenever `Index` stop from an increasing sequence and starts from an index value smaller than the previous index, you can use:

```
df['Group ID'] = df['Index'].diff().lt(0).cumsum() + 1
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Index  Column1 Column2  Group ID
0      0  xxxxxxx    yyyy         1
1      1   xxxxxx     yyy         1
2      2    xxxxx      yy         1
3      0      xxx       y         2
4      1       xx   yyyyy         2
```

Comment: In fact, what I mean is the first condition you mention. Thanks so much, it works.